# Remove double quotes from path variable in PowerShell

Tags: c#, string, powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.1

I'm using PowerShell 5.1.

I have a script that retrieves the HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services<service>\ImagePath value from the registry.  The string that gets returns looks like this:

`"C:\Program Files\Dir1\Dir2"`

Note that the double quotes are part of the string.

I need to get the parent directory for the path represented by this string.  I tried `Split-Path`, but this leaves the leading double quote in the returned value, which causes `Test-Path` to return `false` on a directory that does indeed exist.  For example,

```
$key = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<service>"
$val = "ImagePath"
$dir = Get-RegistryValue $key $val
: "C:\Program Files\Dir1\Dir2"
$parentDir = Split-Path $dir
: "C:\Program Files\Dir1  <--leading double quote
Test-Path $parentDir
: False
```

To get around this, I tried using the `Trim()` call to remove any leading or trailing double-quotes, but that only seems to remove the leading double quote, i.e., the trailing double quote remains in place.  This looks like a bug to me based on my experience with `String.Trim()` in C#.

```
$key = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<service>"
$val = "ImagePath"
$dir = (Get-RegistryValue $key $val).Trim("`"")
: C:\Program Files\Dir1\Dir2"  <-- trailing double quote
```

The only thing that seems to work is to replace the double quotes with an empty string, like so:

```
$key = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<service>"
$val = "ImagePath"
$dir = (Get-RegistryValue $key $val).Replace("`"", "")
: C:\Program Files\Dir1\Dir2  <-- no double quotes
```

However, this just feels wrong to me.  It works in this case given that paths cannot have double quotes, i.e., the double quote character is an illegal path variable.  But what if the returned registry value legitimately had a double quote in the string?  This brute approach would remove that double quote.

I'm still new to PowerShell, so it's very possible that I'm overlooking something that will do what I want to do without requiring me to use the `Replace()` call.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Trim('"')` not working? Perhaps there are also trailing invisible characters.. you coult try `Trim('" ')`

Comment: `Trim('"')` leaves the same trailing quote.  I tried `Trim('" ')` and that works, so there must be some trailing space there.  Didn't think of trying that, so kudos for that.  Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: There are regex methods sure, but Trim is fast and every string has that method, so.. You can also daisy chain: `Trim().Trim('"')` to get rid of all surrounding whitespace first and then unquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe *trailing quote not removed* means there is some invisible character like a space trailing the quote.

To get rid of that too, use `Trim('" ')` or chain two Trim's together like

```
Trim().Trim('"')
```

The first removes all whitespace characters from both sides of the string (not just spaces, but also tabs, newlines etc.), followed by the second one to remove the quotes.

P.S. We cannot see what your function does exactly, but maybe you can use PowerShell's own [Get-ItemPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) for that?

Comment: I'm using `Get-ItemProperty` under the hood.  My `Get-RegistryValue` incorporates some other checks.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if the quote is a fixed thing you can TrimEnd

```
$dir = (Get-RegistryValue $key $val).TrimEnd('"')
```

else you can do a check like so

```
$key = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<service>"
$val = "ImagePath"
$tmp = (Get-RegistryValue $key $val)
$dir = if ($tmp.EndsWith('"')) {$tmp.TrimEnd('"')} else {$tmp}
```

if anyone have a better anwer I would like to see it since I'm alway from powershell since some time